# Python to click a button/link in JavaScript

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, onclick, attributes

I want to show more page by click a button to run a JavaScript function as below:

```
<div class="loading" style="display:none;">
  <p class="btn blue"><span>さらに表示</span></p>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="get_more();"></a>
</div>
```

I tried the code, it doesn't work, what can I do?

```
more_info_button = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get('href=javascript:void(0);')
more_info_button.click()
```

Comment: Try using xpath `//div/a[contains(@onclick,'get_more')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to click link that contains attribute `@href` equal to `"javascript:void(0);"`, try

```
more_info_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="javascript:void(0);"]')
more_info_button.click()
```

Same with CSS selector:

```
more_info_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href="javascript:void(0);"]')
```

To locate link by text in preceding paragraph:

```
more_info_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[preceding-sibling::p[.="さらに表示"]]')
```

**Update**

Try below code to get extended topics list after clicking the button:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

topics_number = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('topics'))
more_info_button.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('topics')) > topics_number)
extended_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('topics')
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I check if page is full loaded after click?

Comment: What exactly you want to do next after click?

Comment: After click button, all rest contents will be extended to show in the same page, I want to parse it after page finishing loaded.

Comment: You might need to implement [ExplicitWait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for new element to be present in DOM/to be visible...

Comment: I am not sure why I got the same result even f the button is clicked. I tried to parse this page `https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/`, the 'more' button is at the bottom of page, can you help me?

Comment: So you want to get extended list of topics after clicking More button right?

Comment: I got it if I run `frame = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("frame")` after click, but I don't know why, can you explain for me?

Comment: I guess it just allows you to wait little more time. This code line, however, is useful. Try updated answer instead